# Is there any Static Code Analysis Tool to verify API REST guidelines?

Tags: api, rest, standards-compliance

Thanks in advance for sharing your ideas and inputs.

We know there are many REST guidelines for API published these days. I use the below for internal code review.

https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md

Is there any way I can automate the code review against the guidelines? Is there any specific tool for the same?

If no, can any of the available tool be configured with custom rules to check against the guidelines?

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Thanks, Neel

Comment: I doubt that an application following the principles of a real REST architecture will be a valid target for static code analysis tools or linters. For all those pseudo "REST" services, that are pure RPC in nature, however, such tools might be available, though as mentioned, they shouldn't be termed REST at all. REST should be used to achieve full decoupling by adhering to few architecture constraints such as statelessness, cachability and focus on HATEOAS.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SwaggerHub which has built in standardisation checking but am playing with spectral to automatically review / lint against our standards.
[API handyman](https://apihandyman.io/)/[Arnaud Lauret](https://www.linkedin.com/in/arnaudlauret)
 has an [excellent series](https://apihandyman.io/api-design-reviewers-starter-set/) on how to do this and how spectral can be used to be an "[Augmented API reviewer](https://apihandyman.io/apidays-interface-doing-apis-right-and-doing-right-apis/#automating-api-design-reviews)"